# Include assets in Twig Extension with Symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, assets

I want to include asset with some script file in Twig extension. E.g. I want to declare twig function `{{ init_project() }}`, but when I writing in my twig function `'<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/js/script.js') }}"></script>'`, it dont work, it return 404 error in debug panel of browser. So how I can do this?

Comment: well you can definetly do it without assetic src="/bundles/mybundle/js/script.js">

Comment: @johnSmith, hm, in debuger i can see, that `assetic` add root of my project directory, like `src="project/web/bundles/mybundle/js/script.js">`, but I will try your way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Look at the `'asset'` twig function :*

*You can find it in `\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Extensions\AssetsExtension`*

```
public function getAssetUrl($path, $packageName = null, $absolute = false, $version = null)
    {
        $url = $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl($path, $packageName, $version);

        if (!$absolute) {
            return $url;
        }

        return $this->ensureUrlIsAbsolute($url);
    }
```

*Instead of calling `'{{asset}}'` in your extension, just call the public function `getAssetUrl()`*