# Test TwigExtension with assetHelper in Symfony2

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, twig, assets

I have a Twig extension and a couple of functions what retruns something like,

`<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$this->assetHelper->getAssetUrl('bundles/mybundle/js/script.js').'"></script>`

But assetHelper require request service. Tests I run in cli, so there is no Request object. How I can test this function?

Comment: Not very clear what is your input and what do you want for your output ? Can you post more information on your twig extension

Comment: I suggest to see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737444/include-assets-in-twig-extension-with-symfony2/28738001#28738001